# Django Sending Mail to smtp.office365.com fails with [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not know

Tags: django, smtp, office365

.env file

```
EMAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
```

settings.py

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
    EMAIL_HOST = env.str("EMAIL_HOST")
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = env.str("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env.str("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
    SERVER_EMAIL = env.str("SERVER_EMAIL")
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = env.str("DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL")
```

The system errors with

```
../3.10/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

The strange part is this configuration worked until a week ago. The system has been solid and error  free since March and just last week all email started failing. Fails from my local machine, fails from my dev server and also fails from my prod server and there has been no code pushes to prod in 2 months. So something must have changed with o365?
I have changed my mail server to sendgrid and the code functions just fine. Does anyone have any advice on how to further troubleshoot this?  Microsoft is useless. Says is its my DNS. Which is incorrect because this is a linux machine running in Azure and will resolve everything else including a telnet on port 587 to smtp.office365.com.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by removing the str on the env.str("EMAIL_HOST")
The new setting looks like

```
EMAIL_HOST = env("EMAIL_HOST")
```